# Apache server .htaccess file won't load at all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know, there are thousands of .htaccess topics out there but I'm looking for days now and can't find an answer.
I want to use .htaccess to redirect from e.g. `https://myserver.com/project/about` to `https://myserver.com/project/about.php` using mod_rewrite.

#### Project structure

in my /var/www/project folder there is

- an about.html containing nothing more than a simple `<h1>` Header
- a .htaccess file containing
  `RewriteEngine on`
  `RewriteRule ^about$ about.html [NC]`

I can access the file with `https://myserver.com/project/about.php`.

#### What I've tried so far

I've looked at my /etc/apache2 folder (I'm running an ubuntu server, apache v. 2.2.22).
In the internet I've found I should add `AllowOverwrite All` somewhere but I couldn't find out where. I've found alot of places where it should go in the internet and tried most of them - without success.
Somehow my files all differ from others.
I've also tried to write in the first line of my /var/www/project/.htaccess `deny from all` or just random things to see if an error 500 gets printed. Nope. No feedback from my .htaccess at all.

#### Files

/etc/apache2/..

- apache2.conf: Containing no `<Directory>` tag.

  ```
  AccessFileName .htaccess
  <Files ~ "^\.ht">
      Order allow,deny
      Deny from all
      Satisfy all
  </Files>
  ```
- httpd.conf: Empty.
- conf-available/php5.6-fpm.conf: Containing no `<Directory>` tag.
- sites-available/default: Empty.
- sites-enabled/default.conf:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      RewriteEngine on
      ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
      RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- sites-enabled/ssl.conf:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
      ...
      DocumentRoot /var/www
      <Directory />
           Options FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
      </Directory>
      <Directory "/var/www/">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
      </Directory>
      ...
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

I hope you can help me because I literally have no single idea anymore.

Comment: You dont say that you checked `httpd.conf` for this line being active `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Comment: What are the file system permissions of that `.htaccess` file?

Comment: `AllowOverride All` is already set for the directory `/var/www` so your .htaccess should work if your website is in there

Comment: as I said httpd.conf is completely empty

Comment: What do you see in your http servers error log files?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes it should and exactly that is my problem..

Comment: .htaccess has 644 rights, user and group are root

Comment: So if you go to `/project/about` what do you see? It should be the contents of `about.html`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Without the rewriting module being enabled the http server would not start given that configuration.

Comment: maybe you need to set `RewriteBase  /project` as well in the `.htaccess`

Comment: @apokryfos /project/about shows me a 404 Not Found error

Comment: @arkascha Ah, right. Obviously one mistake I have not yet made, so no reference point

Comment: @arkascha */var/log/apache2/access.log* is empty

Comment: That _probably_ means that you have not enabled error logging, otherwise that file _can not_ be empty with a running http server. You definitely should enable error logging for obvious reasons. Take a look at the `ErrorLog` directive (see the official documentation for that). Actually I wonder who configured that server? It looks pretty twisted...

Comment: @arkascha It sure does xD that fits to the guy who set it up. Would you say it is the best to just backup all the files and set it up again? Or try to fix it

Comment: Hard to say from our perspective, but it might make sense if you are the one having to take care of it in future. Make sure that you actually remove all files in `/etc/apache2` between deinstallation and reinstallation. Then invest a little time to understand the structure of the files installed by the ubuntu packages. That is no rocket science ;-)